# Compiling gSOAP 2.8.8 package errors

Tags: c++, compilation, gsoap

I was building the gSOAP-2.8.8 package using the autoconf and statements as ./configure, make , make install while using the statement make i got the following errors as:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\bison.exe :cannot open file '/usr/local/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4'
```

and the make is not successfull.

Kindly help me resolving this, any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to build gsoap from source you need to have a number of tools installed, as a minimum you need to make sure you've downloaded and built the latest versions of:
au

- autoconf
- automake
- bison
- flex
- m4

and if you plan on encrypting your SOAP messages then **openssl** is also required.

Based on your error message I suspect the m4 pre-processor may well be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply@Jackson i have most of these :
I have got bison-2.5,flex-2.5.35, openssl1.0.1c,m4-1.4.9,zlib-1.2.7 unzipped at C:/ and their respective folder locations i tried with ./configure,make , makeinstall in all these except for zlib-1.2.7 i got no errors in bison and openssl however when it came to flex while using make it gave an error as regex.h is not found so i stopped that in between and went over to gsoap build , if you could list the exact steps so that i get a complete , simple guide to build the gsoap library.

Comment: @eddie I don't have a full build process for MinGW - on the occasions I've built gsoap it's been on solaris. On Windows I've always just used the pre-built binaries that come with the package.

Comment: The prebult binaries are in the bin/win32 folder so u meant that including the folder's path in the include dirs of a project would work , is that what you meant.

Comment: No - I mean that there are pre-built executables for soapcpp2.exe and wsdl2h.exe included with the gsoap download.